# How to use javascript files in maven project?

Tags: javascript, maven

I'm trying to use javascript in a maven project. My question is how to implement it to maven depencies, So it will work on my html?

Answer (score 0):

I think we need some more information about what you're trying to accomplish. Javascript files would not be included in maven project files, such as pom.xml, but would be imported into the pages that you are using the Javascript in. You can put the Javascript files into the src.main.webapp.javascript directory and then import it into your html page:

`<script src="javascript/myscripts.js"></script>`